# Split json-ld file using apache camel

Tags: java, json, apache-camel, json-ld

I try to split following json-ld file in multiple files (ca. 1000 objects each file) using apache camel.

```
{
   "@context": {
    "books":"http://schema.org/Book",
    "step":"http://schema.org/isbn",
    "pageStart":"http://schema.org/pageStart",
    "pageEnd":"http://schema.org/pageEnd",
    "step":"https://schema.org/step",
    "position":"http://schema.org/position",
    "name":"http://schema.org/name"

  },
  "books":[
    {
      "step" : 1,
      "name" : "甕安縣志目次",
      "isbn" : "00201",
      "pageStart" : 15,
      "pageEnd" : 21,
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "step" : 2,
      "name" : "卷一",
      "isbn" : "00201",
      "pageStart" : 24,
      "pageEnd" : 26,
      "position" : 1
    }, ....
```

In my code i use following:

```
from("file:data")
    .splitt()
    .tokenize(...)
    .to("jms:queue:activemq/queue");
```

How i can get wellformed json-ld objects.

Comment: Use json-path to split the message as its json based - https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-jsonpath/src/main/docs/jsonpath-language.adoc

Comment: One problem, that i have with jsonpath i can't have counter, that split whole books in n parts.  I tried something like this:                                    
   `  for (int i=0; i<2000; i++) {
            String context = JsonPath.parse(jsonObject).read("$.books['step.i']").toString();
        } `

Comment: The tokenizer is NOT for JSon, so you need to build your own, or group them together afterwards, you can use aggregator or some other way.